# Odd twitter meta data description on all pages

Tags: pages, post-meta, seo

On this page – https://cloudmonitor.ai/contact-us/, if you do a View Source, you can see the following meta data:

```
<meta name=”twitter:description” content=”Contact Us Contact For Premium Business Services Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et justo. Praesent mattis commodo augue. Aliquam ornare hendrerit augue Cras tellus In pulvinar lectus. Contact Us Get In Touch 4578 Marmora Road, Glasgow D04 89GR info@demolink.org Call Us At 1-800-1234-567 Request A Free Consultation Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, … Contact Read More »” />
```

It's the same for `og:description`

It looks like it is some default text as a lot of sites have it: https://www.bing.com/search?q=%2C+Glasgow+D04+89GR+info%40demolink.org&cvid=1b9bd5d50b154d4aab0741e8704b9711&aqs=edge..69i57j69i58.237j0j1&pglt=43&FORM=ANNAB1&PC=U531

I check Elementor, I checked the Contact Us page, I checked Metadata under Rankmath Pro (my SEO plugin) and I cannot find out where it is coming from. Has anyone seen this before?

**UPDATE**

Ok, I have made a staging site and removed all plugins. It disappears when I remove Elementor. I know have enabled it and made a completely blank page:   https://staging4.cloudmonitor.ai/test/

I can still see the text:  ""post":{"id":7565,"title":"Test%20%E2%80%93%20CloudMonitor","excerpt":"

Contact Us Contact For Premium Business Services Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et justo. Praesent mattis commodo augue.\u00a0Aliquam ornar"

It's the excerpt for the page. I then made a NEW page (https://staging4.cloudmonitor.ai/newtest/) and it is NOT present. Some some other plugin is injecting this on page creation... I'll go through one by one.

**UPDATE 2**

I have now re-enabled all plugins, and I try to make a new page. The problem no longer happens. So something is adding this to the page excerpt but I cannot narrow it down.

**UPDATE 3**

There are 380 000+ websites out there with this issue:  https://www.google.com/search?q=4578+marmora+road%2C+glasgow+d04+89gr
Looking at some randomly - they COULD be Astra Starter Sites. I will ask them if they know anything about it...

Comment: have you deactivated all plugins then turned them on one by one until the problem returns to identify the culprit?

Comment: Search your plugins and themes for some of the text -- maybe `info@demolink.org` -- perhaps.

Comment: Also, the REST API shows this in your excerpt for that page, are you sure you checked everywhere? Lorem ipsum is common filler text used as a placeholder

Comment: I'll try both of those suggestions and make a staging site clone. I was amazed at how many websites on the web have the same problem

Comment: Removing all plugins did not work - I will try to search for the text info@demo... in the source code now

Comment: clear hosting cache/ flush them, if problem is still there, check your seo plugin if any and remove old meta, if it's still there edit you database table in phpmyadmin

Comment: On my staging site I have turned all caching off. I'll try search my db

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the problem.

At some point in the history of my site I installed a theme which inserted a lot of dummy data. This made pages that have the "Lorem Ipsum" text in the post_excerpt. A year later, I switched to Astra Pro theme and Elementor, which do NOT show the Excerpt editor. I then customised the existing pages and forgot about it, until I noticed it in the search results.

I was able to find it by running this SQL on MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE post_excerpt like '%lorem%'
```

I fixed it like this (run this at your own risk and backup first).

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_excerpt = ''
WHERE post_excerpt like '%lorem%'
```

Then I cleared all caches and checked View Source and it's gone!